# how to get the url of the webView

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a Subview that load a Webview, i want to get the url of the webView when my webView load a site,can you tell me how to get the url of the webView. thank you.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Assuming `webView` is the name of your `WebView`, you could use:

```
String webUrl = webView.getUrl();
```

See Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl()

Answer (score 5):

Also you can use this too

```
String webUrl = webView.getOriginalUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

For preventing the null pointer exception  : `if(webView!=null){
            webView.getUrl();
        }`