# How to store weburl in a string of a website opened in webview on android?

Tags: java, android, string, webview, uri

How to store weburl in a string of a website opened in webview on android ?
my basic requirement is that when i open a website in webview the url of that website should be automatically stored in a string every time i move to next website the previous url should be replaced bt the previous one

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the url of the webView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132258/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-webview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String webUrl = webView.getUrl();
```