# Is there a way for the user to get the URL of the page in Android Webview?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, android-webview

Hello Stack Overflow people. I am new in developing HTML5 apps for Android. I used Webview to accomplish that but then I realized that HTML5 source code can be exposed if the user extract the compiled/built APK file of the app. Now I wonder if we can secure the source code by removing it from the APK file and load that source from a web server instead? If I load the HTML5 source code from the internet will a user be able to get the URL of the Webview's source code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: yep http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132258/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-webview

Comment: Thanks Tasos, I do understand that we can get the URL programmatically inside our code. But how about a hacker? Is there an easy way that they can figure out the URL of the page displayed in my App's Webview? For example maybe there could be tools or techniques they can use to hack and get the URL of my App and if that happens they could just download the source code from that URL. The goal is I want to prevent anyone from stealing the HTML5 source code. Because if hacking webview's URL is easy I would recode my entire app from HTML5 into native Java so that I can protect the source code.

Comment: check here https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/extract-android-apk-view-source-code/

Comment: Oh I see. Even I recode it to native or upload HTML5 source to a web host the source codes can still be extracted. Thus I still need to obfuscate the code. Well thanks allot Tasos.

Comment: The code has be to examined by google for viruses and malware so it needs to be viewed and assessed to protect all the users. Its common sense as the the whole Android project is Open Source. It the backed you need to protect against hackers